# Is there a typo in the paper "Evolution Strategies as a Scalable Alternative to reinforcement learning" by OpenAI?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, neural-networks, mathematical-statistics, reinforcement-learning

Original paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.03864.pdf

---

On page 2-3, it writes,

[image]

But this equation is clearly wrong.

Since the step needed to derive the equation involves the argument, let $$\theta = \psi + \sigma \epsilon, \epsilon \sim N(0,I)$$

Therefore by a straight forward substitution, $$\mathbb{E}_{\theta \sim p_\psi} F(\theta) = \mathbb{E}_{\epsilon \sim N(0,I)} F(\psi + \sigma\epsilon) $$

and NOT,

$$\mathbb{E}_{\theta \sim p_\psi} F(\theta) =\mathbb{E}_{\epsilon \sim N(0,I)} F(\theta + \sigma\epsilon) $$
($\theta$ and $\psi$ exchanged)
as written in the paper. Hence all the rest of the results are wrong.

---

One can argue that the authors, confusingly, implicitly exchanged the notation of $\psi$ and $\theta$, where now $\theta$ refers to the mean of the Gaussian distribution (which was previously denoted by $\psi$)

However, this implies that their main algorithm is wrong,
[image]

Because $\theta$ here is clearly not the mean of the Gaussian. $\theta$ clearly refers to the neural network parameter (weights) in the original paper.

Can someone check for me?

Note that this error is also pointed out in an earlier post [How is the equation in "Evolution Strategies as a Scalable Alternative to Reinforcement Learning" derived?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/348111/how-is-the-equation-in-evolution-strategies-as-a-scalable-alternative-to-reinfo)
however, in my opinion this is not just an abuse of notation "confusing" but it is flat out wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is the equation in "Evolution Strategies as a Scalable Alternative to Reinforcement Learning" derived?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/348111/how-is-the-equation-in-evolution-strategies-as-a-scalable-alternative-to-reinfo)

Comment: @Xi'an No. The answer said "$\theta$ to be the "mean parameter vector". But as I have pointed out in my question, the way that $\theta$ is updated in algorithm 1 does not imply that $\theta$ is the mean parameter vector, but the original weights of the neural network. Unless, we take the weights of the neural network to be the mean of a Gaussian....which the paper does not claim.

Answer (score 1):

- For the first question, I think the authors just exchange the notations $\psi$ and $\theta$.
- For the second question, the weights of neural networks are modeled as Gaussian variables with distribution $\mathcal{N}(\theta, \sigma^2I)$.